# Sending file with SOAP MTOM using PowerShell

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap, mtom

I am attempting to send a SOAP message with PowerShell that uses MTOM to attach an XML file. MTOM is the method specified by the web service so I don't have the option to include the XML file inline.

I'm getting confused when it comes to actually attaching the file to the SOAP message. I understand that the file is attached using the `<xop:Include>` element in the SOAP message. But how do I specify the value that should be included for the `href` attribute (i.e. how do I determine the string that should replace `xxxxxxxxx`?

In all the examples that I've seen up to now the value for `href` is always specified as something like `0ccceb3ce8deda6a3a666b587962a26a7524fe64d35d73ea@apache.org` but I don't understand how this is generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:RequestAttInfo xmlns:ns1="urn:abb.com:project/isem/types">
            <requestType xmlns="">mp.report</requestType>
            <adminRole xmlns="">false</adminRole>
            <requestDataCompressed xmlns="">false</requestDataCompressed>
            <requestDataType xmlns="">XML</requestDataType>
            <sendRequestDataOnSuccess xmlns="">true</sendRequestDataOnSuccess>
            <sendResponseDataCompressed xmlns="">false</sendResponseDataCompressed>
            <requestSignature xmlns="">yyyyyyyyy</requestSignature>
            <requestData xmlns="">
                <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:xxxxxxxxx"></xop:Include>
            </requestData>
        </ns1:RequestAttInfo>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but is that not just a mime attachment?

Comment: @owainesau It is included as a MIME attachment. My understanding is that the `<xop: Include>` element is used to specify the MIME attachment. But I don't understand how the href value is generated.

Comment: this may help: https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-python-gitbook-free/e-mail_composition_and_decoding/composing_mime_attachments.html

Comment: @OwainEsau Thanks for that but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. This is a MIME attachment for an email. Although the MIME part is the same I'm specifically interested in MIME attachments in SOAP messages